# JavaScript version of .each loop using element type and id wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Is there a JavaScript version of the following. It works as I want, but it looks a bit messy and I've read that sometimes breaking from an outer for loop within a .each loop is more neatly achieved with Javascript.

```
for(array to iterate over){
    var abSelected = false;
    $("input[type='checkbox'][id*=AB]:checked").each(function() {
      abSelected = true;
    }
    if(abSelected){
      break;
    }
...do other stuff...
}
```

I think the if statement is unnecessary. I want to loop all checkboxes beginning with 'AB' and break from the outer for loop if any are selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you testing the same check boxes inside the loop? The other stuff is done AFTER the test, so IMHO you could do the check box test only on start (i.e. outside the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check on the length of the `selected checkboxes beginning with 'AB'` collection returned by jQuery, if > 0, break:

```
for(array to iterate over){
    if($("input[type='checkbox'][id*=AB]:checked").length > 0)
        break;
...do other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it - i really got to get a better hold of using the editor here :P

Comment: @freakfm, might be worth taking a look at the [mark-down help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/). :)

Comment: How could I be so foolish. Forgot about count completely. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to loop all the checkboxes.
You could just use `$('input[type='checkbox'][id*=AB]:checked').length`

This will get you the count of all checked checkboxes.

Comment: Slightly more concisely `$('input:checkbox[id*AB]:checked').length`. Reference: [`:checkbox`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector).